# Emploi de l'adjectif tertiaire comme dans "l'enseignement tertiaire"

Tags: usage, adjectifs

L'adjectif *tertiaire* est-il couramment employé en français ?

Par exemple, l'expression *[enseignement tertiaire](http://www.oecd.org/fr/education/innovation-education/37412948.pdf)*, signifiant enseignement postsecondaire, serait-elle généralement comprise ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Le terme d'enseignement tertiaire n'est pas compris par la majorité des gens en France, même de ceux ayant fait des études supérieures ou travaillant dans l'enseignement supérieur, c'est un terme utilisé presque uniquement par l'OCDE, c'est donc plus un terme connu des politiques et des sociologues que de l'ensemble de la population. Le terme désigne la majeure partie de  l'enseignement post secondaire (en France après le bac) et pas uniquement l'enseignement universitaire.

Voici un extrait d'un [rapport du Sénat](https://www.senat.fr/rap/r07-442/r07-4420.html) qui explique pourquoi le terme n'est pas utilisé en France et ce qu'il regroupe selon la nomenclature française.

> Le terme d'enseignement « tertiaire » est utilisé conjointement à celui d'enseignement « supérieur » par les instances internationales : l'OCDE préfère le premier, tandis que l'**Union européenne et l'UNESCO privilégient plutôt le second**.<sup>1</sup>
>
> Le terme d'enseignement « tertiaire » (ou postsecondaire) est utilisé dans le but de tenir compte de la diversité des programmes et institutions disponibles après l'achèvement d'un niveau d'éducation secondaire. D'après les conventions statistiques internationales, l'éducation tertiaire correspond aux niveaux 5A, 5B et 6 de la classification internationale type de l'éducation (CITE).

[...]

> 4 : Enseignement postsecondaire non tertiaire <sup>2</sup>
>
> 5B : Enseignement tertiaire axé sur l'acquisition de qualifications pratiques, techniques et professionnelles en vue d'une entrée directe sur le marché du travail
>
> 5 A: Enseignement tertiaire permettant d'acquérir les compétences suffisantes pour accéder à des programmes de recherche de haut niveau
>
> 6 : Deuxième cycle de l'enseignement supérieur, conduisant à un titre de chercheur de haut niveau.

---

<sup>1</sup> : c'est moi qui souligne.

<sup>2</sup> : le niveau 4A prépare les élèves à accéder à des formations de l’enseignement tertiaire (ou « supérieur »), à la fois de niveau universitaire et à finalité professionnelle ; le niveau 4B en
règle générale prépare les élèves à entrer dans la vie active).

Answer (score 3):

Il ne s'agit pas d'une expression très répandue dans ce contexte, à mon sens l'adjectif tertiaire est le plus souvent utilisé quand on parle d'un secteur d'activité (le *secteur tertiaire* peut même être raccourcis en *tertiaire* seul).

On désigne alors ici le secteur des services, le premier secteur étant l'agriculture et le second l'industrie.

D'une façon plus globale on parlerait de l'enseignement supérieur au lieu de parler de l'enseignement tertiaire.

Comment: Non pour ce qui est de ton dernier paragraphe. L'Enseignement Supérieur correspond à un cadre institutionnel. Or, le cadre 5A du document lié dans l'OP précise le champ : E. tertiaire = Enseignement Supérieur ** + celui prodigué par des instances non institutionnelles. ** Auquel cas, c'est l'E.T. qui serait plus *global*

Comment: L'OP parle bien de l'enseignement "postsecondaire", je n'ai pas pris la peine de lire le document.